# .Net C# post form to external URL

Tags: c#, webforms

I am new to .NET - I have been a classic ASP developer for a while.
I am trying to post an HTML form to saleforce and I am having some issues.
I am using .NET webforms 4.0 with a master page.

If I was doing this in classic ASP, I would simply change the form action to the Salesforce URL. But with webforms, I guess the form is submitting back to the page.

I think I am supposed to postback and collect the data form the form and then send it to salesforce, but I am not sure how to do that...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have your own asp.net page with some form fields on it, and you want to submit that form to another server?

Comment: yes, its a contact form that needs to be fed into Salesforce. I have the URL that i need to send it to and the form fields, But I am having trouble processing the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply: don't use a webform (`runat="server"`) and instead just create a regular old form.  Then set the `action` attribute to post to salesforce and you're done.

This would be how you'd do it compared to the classic ASP method, which doesn't have webforms (viewstate, viewbag, etc).

Comment: thanks! that works well - so to confirm, my webform pages dont need a form that is runat="server"  ? I removed the form from my master page, and now the only page with a form is the contact page. is this okay?

Comment: You only need that if you want it to maintain postback information through viewstate.  If you want a regular old dumb form, no need to bloat your page with a webform form.

I'm not a fan of putting the forms in the master page.  You lose control over the form.  I prefer to explicitly put my forms in the pages, even if it is somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webclient and UploadValues in the postback event to post to external Url. This will keep you on your website aswell, but if you want to end up to on the external website, this solution wont work.

```
System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
myWebClient.UploadValues(ExternUrl, PostData);
```